# Drow magic are learned?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, drow

Drow spell are learned, can use slots to cast more than one time or use higher slots to increast power?

Comment: What drow spells are you asking about exactly? Are you perhaps referring to dunamancy from the upcoming *Explorer's guide to Wildemount*?

Comment: Are we talking about NPC Drow or the PC race?